# Run line of javascript code over multiple pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, curl

I want to run a simple line of code:

```
document.getElementById('..').click();document.getElementById('..').click();
```

over multiple pages of the same website. I have a list of all those pages, I want to open the page, click those two elements and close the page over - 700 times. Can I possibly program chromium console to do that(taking into account loading times)?

Comment: It maybe worthwhile looking up Selenium (a testing tool) which should be able to do this pretty easily for you. Look here -http://docs.seleniumhq.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this task.

[Here is an article with very detailed explanations](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/12/build-cli-tool-nodejs-phantomjs/). Maybe it's enough to look at the examples on PhantomJS page.

Comment: Thanx for the tip, I will take a closer look on that later, it is huge at the first glance, will turn usefull. For now I installed simple macro recorder on chromium it will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (it should work from almost any browser's console)

First you need to be on the same website that your pages belong to and you should also allow pop-up windows to be displayed for this website.

```js
const pages = ['https://example.com/page_1', 'https://example.com/page_2', ...]; //Your list of page links (relative or absolute)

async function doAutomatedStuff(links) { //Use 'async' to make use of 'await' later
    for (const link of links) {
        let page = window.open(link, '', "location=no, toolbar=0, width=600, height=600"); //Must be executed from the same website and pop-ups are allowed
        page.onload = function (event) { //Executed after the whole page is loaded
            page.document.getElementById('..').click();
            //If your click() event does something async, you may want to wait for it first before closing the page
            page.close();
        };
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000)); //Wait and block (delay) for a reasonable amount of time before proceeding to the next link
    }
}

doAutomatedStuff(pages); //Execute
```

Keep in mind that you need to put some delay between processing one link and the next, otherwise you'll get too many pop-ups and the browser may crash.

In addition, browsers limit the number of open pop-ups for each website, I think this can be changed in browser's configurations but I recommend that you reset it after you finish.

Use in anonymous or incognito mode to avoid cluttering your history